# Two different ELBs for a single ElasticBeanstalk environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to have two ElasticLoadBalancers for an ElasticBeanstalk environment; one internal and another external.

The configuration dashboard does not have any means to add more ELBs (and although I could add one manually, it wouldn't keep up with the instances automatically as they are added or removed by autoscaling and deployment changes), and I'm not sure if I can somehow add it with some CLI or API magic (maybe I can add the extra ELB to the ElasticBeanstalk automatically generated autoscaling group, but I think that might be one of those things that you cannot edit after it has been created).

I know that I could do it with Cloudformation, but it seems overly complicated for such a small thing...

Comment: Can you explain your usecase in a bit more detail regarding internal and external ELB?

Comment: I need to access the service from the outside world (security group with whitelisted IP addresses for my offices), hence the external ELB; and with no restrictions for other services running within the VPC, hence the internal ELB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your usecase I will recommend creating one environment per service. That gives you failure isolation for your environments. You can configure your VPC subnets for each of your environments environments (and hence ELBs) to get external and internal services.